# C++ How to override class field with a different type (without template)?

Tags: c++, inheritance, polymorphism, overriding

So I am trying to write a simple interpreter in c++, but ran into some problems. I have a `Token` class, which holds an enum `TokenType`, and a `TokenValue` object. The `TokenValue` class is the base class of several other classes (`TV_String`, `TV_Int`, and `TV_Float`).

Here is the code for the `TokenValue` and its children classes:

```cpp
// TokenValue.h

class TokenValue
{
public:
    void* value = NULL;

    virtual bool operator ==(const TokenValue& tv) const
    {
        return typeid(this) == typeid(tv) && value == tv.value;
    }
};

class TV_Empty : public TokenValue {};

class TV_String : public TokenValue
{
public:
    std::string value;

    TV_String(std::string value); // The constructors just assign the value argument to the value field
};

class TV_Int : public TokenValue
{
public:
    int value;

    TV_Int(int value);
};

class TV_Float : public TokenValue
{
public:
    float value;

    TV_Float(float value);
};
```

Here's the code for `Token`:

```cpp
// Token.h

class Token
{
public:
    enum class TokenType
    {
        // all the different types
    }

    TokenType type;
    TokenValue value;

    Token(TokenType type, TokenValue value); // just initialises type and value, nothing else
}
```

The problem I am having is that the `value` field is not being changed when I use any of the children classes (it always shows 00000000 when I print it, I assume that's the value of `void* value = NULL`, but not sure). From research I think it could be solved by using templates, but in my case I can't use templates because `Token` never know the type of its corresponding `TokenValue`.

So how can I override the type and value of the `value` field and access the correct `value` in the children classes, and in the == operator?

(Thanks to Jarod42 I realised it doesn't "override" the field, it creates a new field with a different type and the same name.)

Comment: Notice that `TV_String` has 2 unrelated members named `value`: `TokenValue::value` and `TV_String::value`.

Comment: `std::variant` might be more appropriate.

Comment: @Jarod42 Ohh so it doesn't "override" the field, but it creates a new field with a different type and the same name? Then how would I access the value field in the children classes? And how would I use the operator to compare two objects? (I will update in the question)

Comment: @Jarod42 Alright thank you, I will have a look at std::variant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are attempting to do will not work, because `TokenValue` is a base class and you are storing it **by value** in `Token`, so if you attempt to assign a `TV_String` object, a `TV_Int` object, etc to `Token::value`, you will [slice that object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/274626/), losing all info about the derived class type and its data fields.

To work with polymorphic classes correctly, you will need to make the `Token::value` field be **a pointer** to a `TokenValue` object instead, eg:

```cpp
class TokenValue
{
public:
    virtual ~TokenValue() = default;

    virtual bool equals(const TokenValue*) const = 0;

    bool operator==(const TokenValue &rhs) const {
        return equals(&rhs);
    }
};

class TV_Empty : public TokenValue {
public:
    bool equals(const TokenValue* tv) const override {
        return (dynamic_cast<const TV_Empty*>(tv) != nullptr);
    }
};

class TV_String : public TokenValue
{
public:
    std::string value;

    TV_String(const std::string &value) : value(value) {}

    bool equals(const TokenValue* tv) const override {
        TV_String *s = dynamic_cast<const TV_String*>(tv);
        return (s) && (s->value == value);
    }
};

class TV_Int : public TokenValue
{
public:
    int value;

    TV_Int(int value) : value(value) {}

    bool equals(const TokenValue* tv) const override {
        TV_Int *i = dynamic_cast<const TV_Int*>(tv);
        return (i) && (i->value == value);
    }
};

class TV_Float : public TokenValue
{
public:
    float value;

    TV_Float(float value) : value(value) {}

    bool equals(const TokenValue* tv) const override {
        TV_Float *f = dynamic_cast<const TV_Float*>(tv);
        return (f) && (f->value == value);
    }
};

...
```

```cpp
struct EmptyToken {};

class Token
{
public:
    enum class TokenType
    {
        Empty,
        String,
        Int,
        Float
        ...;
    };

    TokenType type;
    std::unique_ptr<TokenValue> value;

    static TokenType GetTokenType(const TokenValue *tv) {
        if (dynamic_cast<TV_Empty*>(tv) != nullptr)
            return TokenType::Empty;
        if (dynamic_cast<TV_String*>(tv) != nullptr)
            return TokenType::String;
        if (dynamic_cast<TV_Int*>(tv) != nullptr)
            return TokenType::Int;
        if (dynamic_cast<TV_Float*>(tv) != nullptr)
            return TokenType::Float;
        return ...;
    }

    Token(std::unique_ptr<TokenValue> value) : Token(GetTokenType(value.get()), std::move(value)) {}

    Token(TokenType type, std::unique_ptr<TokenValue> value) : type(type), value(std::move(value)) {}

    explicit Token(const EmptyToken &) : type(TokenValue::Empty), value(std::make_unique<TV_Empty>()) {}
    explicit Token(const std::string &value) : type(TokenValue::String), value(std::make_unique<TV_String>(value)) {}
    explicit Token(int value) : type(TokenValue::Int), value(std::make_unique<TV_Int>(value)) {}
    explicit Token(float value) : type(TokenValue::Float), value(std::make_unique<TV_Float>(value)) {}
    ...
};
```

```cpp
Token tk1(std::string("test"));
Token tk2(12345);
if (*(tk1.value) == *(tk2.value)) ...
if (tk1.value->equals(tk2.value.get())) ...
...
```

However, what you are essentially doing is replicating what [`std::variant`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant) already is (a tagged union), so you should get rid of `TokenValue` completely and just use `std::variant` instead, eg:

```cpp
struct EmptyToken {};

class Token
{
public:
    enum class TokenType
    {
        Empty,
        String,
        Int,
        Float
        ...;
    };

    std::variant<EmptyToken, std::string, int, float, ...> value;

    explicit Token(const EmptyToken &value) : value(value) {}
    explicit Token(const std::string &value) : value(value) {}
    explicit Token(int value) : value(value) {}
    explicit Token(float value) : value(value) {}
    ...

    TokenType GetTokenType() const
    {
        static const TokenType types[] = {TokenType::Empty, TokenType::String, TokenType::Int, TokenType::Float, ...};
        return types[value.index()];
    };

    ...
};
```

```cpp
Token tk1(std::string("test"));
Token tk2(12345);
if (tk1.value == tk2.value) ...
...
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a somewhat nasty situation, but it can be handled with a bit of indirection:

```
struct TokenValue {
    virtual bool equals(const TokenValue&) const = 0;
};

bool operator==(const TokenValue& lhs, const TokenValue& rhs) {
    return typeid(lhs) == typeid(rhs) && lhs.equals(rhs);
}
```

Now, derived classes can have their own `value` field (if that's appropriate), and override `equals`, knowing that the argument will always be their own type:

```
struct TV_empty : TokenValue {
    bool equals(const TokenValue&) const { return true; }
};

struct TV_string : TokenValue {
    std::string value;
    bool equals(const TokenValue& other) const {
        return value == static_cast<TV_string&>(other).value;
    }
}
```

and so on.

Yes, if you're paranoid, you could use `dynamic_cast` inside the `equals` functions.

Comment: @ÖöTiib -- of course. Fixed, thanks.